# Access remove line break in string, program tells it's NULL

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have code that does something then you press enter in textfield, problem is when you use Ctrl+Enter, i can capture that event but access tells me in next line that that field is apparently NULL

```
Private Sub Text5_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
If KeyAscii = vbKeyReturn Or KeyAscii = 10 Then
    If Len(Me.Text5) = 0 Then Exit Sub


    If Val(Right(Me.Text5, 1)) > 2 Then Me.Text5 = Left(Me.Text5, Len(Me.Text5) - 1) & "0"
```

So 'Len' works fine, but the 'Right' function gives out 'Invalid use of null', when i hit debug and check the value it is NULL

I can't figure it out

I guess i need to remove new line characters but how to do that when the text box is null and every function for strings spits out that error

Comment: One way would be to add another check `If IsNull(Me.Text5) Then Exit Sub`.

Comment: So is the problem that once you press enter the text field is no longer length 0, so even though it’s null it gets past your null check?

Comment: i press enter, everything is fine but when i press enter+ctrl (with is KeyAscii = 10 supposedly) then even that i have text in my text box it says that Me.Text5 is null

Comment: Put a break-point on the first line. When you hit the break-point, type `?Len(Me.Text5)` in the Immediate Window. What does it return?

Comment: ok, i was wrong a little, but still, why the text field with actual text in it say NULL when i press Ctrl+enter, but works fine with just enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i test it as much as i can and it's just that when you use Ctrl+Enter on a field and capture the key press, field will be null for some reason, i don't see possible way around this

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your check is that `Len(Null)` is not `0`, it's `Null`.

There are a couple ways to get around this.  First, as mentioned in the comments, you can simply add a check for `IsNull`:

```
If IsNull(Me.Text5) Or Len(Me.Text5) = 0 Then
```

The other way you can do this is force it to coalesce by concatenating `vbNullString`:

```
If Len(Me.Text5 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
```

Comment: @Mr-Auto I didn't make any claim that it wouldn't. I have no clue *what* is in `Me.Text5` at any given time. The claim I did make is that "`Len(Null)` is not `0`", and if you have bound controls that test is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Also you could use `Nz` and set a return value of your wish in case if the expression is null, in this example also `vbNullString` and check the result of this function:

```
If Nz(Me.Text5, vbNullString) = vbNullString Then
```

or

```
If Len(Nz(Me.Text5, vbNullString) = 0) Then
```

or

```
If Nz(Me.Text5, 0) = 0 Then
```

or

```
If Not Nz(Me.Text5, False) Then
```

For sure you can store the result in a variable first and then check and work with this later on.
Whatever fulfills your needs.